# Extra spaces add on making link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am making dynamic menu, fetching values from database and making it a link by using **a** tag but extra spaces add automatically before and after the the link, i don not know why. in database the field is **nvarchar**. further questions may be appreciated.

here is the code structure which i am using to make link.

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <a data-parent="#Leftmenu" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" href="#somelink">
    <img src="Images/menu-bullet-close.png"/>
        Some Text
    </a>
   </li>
<li>
    <a data-parent="#Leftmenu" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" href="#somelink2">
    <img src="Images/menu-bullet-close2.png"/>
        Some Text2
    </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information to assist you with here.  What does the html-generating code look like?  What does the database in the table look like?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extra spaces'? This is about &nbsp; code? or you mean about UI (padding, margin etc.)?

Comment: if the original text is "some text" after makin it a link it will become 
"&nbsp;Some Text&nbsp;"

Comment: @ThomasStringer: it is a left menu of my website, it generates a clickable menu.

Comment: your image tag isn't closed.. i'd close it and put the "Some Text" on the same line as the img.. i'd even make the whole <a> </a> one line and see if that helps